# WPF binding static list to combobox

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

Trying to understand how to bind this static list to a combobox that located on different window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public static List<Classes.Entity> EntityList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        EntityList = new List<Classes.Entity>();    
        InitializeComponent();   
    }
    ...
```

the object:

```
 public class Entity
{
    public string entityName { get; set; }
 ...
```

XAML (In a diffrent window, call "NewRelationship.xaml.cs"

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_from" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EntityList}" DisplayMemberPath="entityName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Entity}"  />
```

Of course I fill the list later in the code...
if I moving the list to the newRelationship window and add "this.datacontext = this;" its working, 
How do I make this work when the list is in the mainWindow?   Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to keep the `EntityList` in a separate object that both windows could reference:

```
class ViewModel
{
    private List<Classes.Entity> _entityList = new List<Classes.Entity>();
    public IEnumerable<Classes.Entity> EntityList
    {
        get { return _entityList; }
    }
}

partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

When the second window is created, you can pass an instance of the `ViewModel` class to it, and set it as the `DataContext`.

Comment: Great, Thank you! now after I create an instanse of ViewModel ("this.DataContext = new ViewModel();")  how do I pass it to the new window? from the MainWindow I have this code - "nrWindow nr = new nrWindow(); nr.ShowDialog();"   Sorry for the newbie questions... thanks again.

Comment: @user2355639 I would just add a parameter to the `nrWindow` constructor for the `ViewModel`.